# Not able to define public acsess modifier inside main activity in android studio v4.2

Tags: java, android-studio-4.2

im not able to declare public class download inside my main class in android studiov4.2

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Intialistion of variables:
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    //declaration of variables :
    listView = findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);  
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    public class Download extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return null;
        }
      }
    }
  }



[Screenshot of error is attached see it for refrence][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbqDY.png
```

Error - Modifier 'public' not allowed here

Comment: which is normal. a Java file can only contain one (non static) public class

Comment: If you indent your code consistently, you'll see that you try to declare a class inside the body of the `onCreate()` method. And that doesn't make sense in Java. I'd recommend that you read some material about the overall structure of multi-class Java programs.

Comment: hi, but can you please clear why it's allowing me to declare class as default , when i declare same DOWNLOAD CLASS as default class (access specifer) it is not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, error solved - I was creating **public Class DownLoad** inside **OnCreate method** , Reality is you just can't create a class inside a method that is already inside a class called "Main". aka - ***Methods can be created inside class***, ***not wise-versa***. Sorry for the silly mistake .